# Spring MVC Hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Spring MVC program with Hibernate. Here is the code.

welcome-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        ">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="EmployeeService" class="java4s.EmployeeServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IMS"
    p:username="user"
    p:password="pass" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IMS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <mapping class="java4s.Employee"></mapping>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Employee.java

```
package java4s;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.Size;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;


@Entity
@Table(name="EmployeeInfo")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userid;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "birthdate", nullable = false)
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "emailid")
    private String emailid;

    @Column(name = "mobileno")
    private String mobileno;

    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public int getUserid()
    {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(int userid)
    {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname)
    {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getMobileno()
    {
        return mobileno;
    }
    public void setMobileno(String mobileno)
    {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return emailid;
    }
    public void setEmail(String emailid)
    {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }
    public Date getBirthdate()
    {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthdate(Date birthDate)
    {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    public String getProfession()
    {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession)
    {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
}
```

Error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginSuccessController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java4s.EmployeeService java4s.LoginSuccessController.emp_service; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java4s.EmployeeService java4s.LoginSuccessController.emp_service; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:976)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:781)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:711)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:520)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:357)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.MappingException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:976)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:781)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:711)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:520)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:357)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Why I am getting this error ?

**EDIT**

Libraries

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
hibernate3.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jsch-0.1.49.jar
jstl-api.jar
jstl-impl.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.11.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
ojdbc6.jar
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar
xerces-2.6.2.jar
```

Comment: HIbernate jars are not available in your WEB-INF/lib/. Another possibility is you are using an incomatible version of hibernate

Comment: You're using a lot of out-of-date info. Go to start.spring.io, and it'll generate a working project skeleton for you with all the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `MappingException` exists in the `hibernate-core` jar. But I think you have it in the classpath. A problem may be with this

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

It is correct only if you use Hibernate 3.

And you don't need to specify this

```
<property name="configurationClass">
  <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
```

**Updated**

You use Hibernate 4 with Spring 4 so you need to use

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

WTF??

```
hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
hibernate3.jar

hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
```

There are a lot of problems with libraries in your classpath try to rebuild your class path using @chrylis advice with http://start.spring.io/.

Comment: That error is gone. Still one error I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z`

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava  You have incompatible libraries versions in your class path.  Please, add your pom or list of jars in your question.

Comment: I have added the libraries list.

Comment: Thanks. I will look for the online builder. Is it something I can do here or you got the problem?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava You just have incorrect jars in your class path. Your jars should have names with a version like this `hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar` not like this `hibernate-core.jar`.

Comment: I have used `hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar` not `hibernate-core.jar`.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava It was just an example. I mean this `hibernate-commons-annotations.jar` and this `hibernate3.jar`.

Comment: I got these files downloaded in a package. OK, I will use http://start.spring.io/ to build a new project. Do I need to manually include hibernate jars or how could I get them?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava It will be better if you will use maven or gradle to add all Hibernate stuff with gradle need only one line in the gradle build `compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.9.Final'`. Or you can just copy jars from new generated project in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Change your sessionFactory bean class to

> `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Answer (score 1):

You should use LocalSessionFactoryBean

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

@Harshit

1. Which version of SpringFramework you are using?
2. If you are Spring 3.X and above version, Please use **only these** Jar's defined in Bill Of Materials link [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-framework-bom%22)
3. Also, you should use appropriate hibernate Jars to match with Spring version Jars

Comment: Please remove the Spring 3.X jars from your dependencies, which will resolve your problem

Comment: I am using spring framework 4.1.1. Initially spring with jdbctemplate, was working fine. But as I tried to integrate hibernate,it start generating error.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You should add his name to your comment to notify him